# Delphi: Undefined record variable

Tags: delphi, record, null

I have defined a `TCGTable` record type with the following structure:

```
type
  TCGTable = record
    x : array [1 .. MAX_POINTS] of Single;
    y : array [1 .. MAX_POINTS] of Single;
  end;
```

I have declared a `TCGTable` variable `CGTable`.

The variable `CGTable` is assigned a particular constant `TCGTable` record value if that record meets several runtime conditions.

If no constant `TCGTable` record meets these conditions, `CGTable` should be undefined.

Is there a Delphi 2010 built-in value I can assign to `CGTable` to indicate that it is undefined? I have tried using the values `nil` and `null`, but both of these seem to be valid only for pointer or variant types. The source will not compile with these values assigned to `CGTable`.

I would like to inspect the variable `CGTable` to determine its validity instead of, for example, maintaining some additional boolean validity flag.

The only workarounds I can determine are:

a) Change the type of `CGTable` to a `TCGTable` pointer (`CGTable : ^TCGTable;`), which would then allow me to compare `CGTable` to the `nil` value.

b) Define some constant `TCGTable` record to act as an "invalid" record. I would then compare `CGTable` against this "invalid" record.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? Thanks

Comment: Approach (b) was my first idea, but you must be sure that there will never be a *valid* `TCGTable` that looks like that.

Comment: With approach (b) you have to check MAX_POINTS * 2 * SizeOf(Single) bytes to determine whether a TCGTable is valid, though.

Comment: You can have a validity flag and inspect the record itself at the same time. That is you can include the flag in the record.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I'd define `TSinglePointArray = Array[1..MAX_POINTS] of Single` and use that for X and Y. It's not necessarily relevant to your question, but it saves on code replication!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a record containing a [static array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Static_Arrays). This particular record has a size equal to `ElementCount*SizeOf(Element)`.

Judging by the the fact that your array is sized with a `MAX_POINTS` constant it looks like you have a variable number of points in the array. I think I would be inclined to switch to dynamic arrays like this:

```
type
  TSinglePoint = record
    x: Single;
    y: Single;
  end;
  TSinglePointArray = array of TSinglePoint;
```

Now if you have a variable, `a: TSinglePointArray`, then a value of `nil` indicates that it is empty or nil. You can query for the length of the array with `Length(a)`. You can resize the array with `SetLength(a, NewLength)`.

Comment: +1 I guess this is the more natural way to implement the expected behavior with Delphi. Such a TSinglePointArray variable will be set to nil by the compiler automatically, even if declared on the stack. And, as a benefit (?), all a[].X and a[].Y fields will be filled with 0 by SetLength, whereas a static array content will be undefined.

Comment: I do indeed have a variable number of points in my arrays, but the arrays are declared as const. The MAX_POINTS variable simply refers to the largest number of points of all these constant arrays. I'm not sure how you would use dynamic arrays in this scenario. Instead I have changed the type of the CGTable variable to a TCGTable pointer, so that I'm initializing and comparing CGTable to nil after trying to locate a valid const TCGTable.

Comment: I do like the TSinglePoint idea though. I will replace my duplicate arrays with this.

Answer (score 1):

No, your record holds as many bytes as its members take up.[*] If any combination of four bytes is a valid Single, and no more bytes are available for additional information, it becomes impossible to store the fact that the record is invalid somewhere.

You could decide that to mark a TCGTable as invalid, you set CGTable.x[1] to NaN. To check whether it is invalid, you can then check IsNaN(CGTable.x[1]). This only works if all valid TCGTables will have x[1] set to a real value, though. Or you could choose another value that is never valid for x[1]. If there is no such value, you will have to create room for the extra information to be able to check the validity, possibly by storing a pointer to a TCGTable, possibly by adding an IsValid field to your record.

[*] This is not true for all records, but almost definitely is in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your array types to dynamic arrays then you could check the lengths of them for your invalid record (both at length zero, for instance).  Since you're using Delphi 2010 you could also use methods defined in your record to assign values, validate your ranges, and determine if the record is valid.